# After 0 kbd macro iterations: read-kbd-macro: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size

Tags: keyboard-macros

Here my kbd macros in `mycustom.el`

```
(fset 'keep-tv-channels-names
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([134217848 107 101 return 69 88 84 73 78 70 return 134217848 81 85 69 82 return 46 42 44 return return 33 24 19] 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

And when I apply it on first file it's correct work.
Nice.
But if I want again to apply it to another file I get error:

```
After 0 kbd macro iterations: read-kbd-macro: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size
```